# Unity - Improve Mesh generation and rendering performance

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, mesh

since I just recently started looking into meshes, how they work, what they do and so on, I decided to use my own calculations to create a mesh of a circle. Unfortunately though, this is really, really slow!

So I am looking for tips on improvements, to make it slow only (because that's probably the best it will get...)

Here is the code I use to generate a circle:

```
public static void createCircle(MeshFilter meshFilter, float innerRadius, float outerRadius, Color color, float xPosition = 0, float yPosition = 0, float startDegree = 0, float endDegree = 360, int points = 100)
         {
             Mesh mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
             mesh.Clear();

             //These values will result in no (or very ugly in the case of points < 10) circle, so let's safe calculation and just return an empty mesh!
             if (startDegree == endDegree || points < 10 || innerRadius >= outerRadius || innerRadius < 0 || outerRadius <= 0)
             {
                 return;
             }

             //The points for the full circle shall be whatever is given but if its not the full circle we dont need all the points!
             points = (int)(Mathf.Abs(endDegree - startDegree) / 360f * points);

             //We always need an uneven number of points!
             if (points % 2 != 0) { points++; }

             Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[points];
             float degreeStepSize = (endDegree - startDegree) * 2 / (points - 3);
             float halfRadStepSize = (degreeStepSize) * Mathf.Deg2Rad / 2f;
             float startRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * startDegree;
             float endRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * endDegree;

             //Let's save the vector at the beginning and the one on the end to make a perfectly straight line
             vertices[0] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(startRad) * outerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(startRad) * outerRadius + yPosition, 0);
             vertices[vertices.Length - 1] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(endRad) * innerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(endRad) * innerRadius + yPosition, 0);

             for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Length - 1; i++)
             {
                 //Pure coinsidence that saved some calculatons. Half Step Size is the same as what would needed to be calculated here!
                 float rad = (i - 1) * halfRadStepSize + startRad;
                 if (i % 2 == 0)
                 {
                     vertices[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rad) * outerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(rad) * outerRadius + yPosition, 0);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     vertices[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rad) * innerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(rad) * innerRadius + yPosition, 0);
                 }
             }
             mesh.vertices = vertices;

             int[] tri = new int[(vertices.Length - 2) * 3];
             for (int i = 0; i < (vertices.Length - 2); i++)
             {
                 int index = i * 3;
                 if (i % 2 == 0)
                 {
                     tri[index + 0] = i + 0;
                     tri[index + 1] = i + 2;
                     tri[index + 2] = i + 1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     tri[index + 0] = i + 0;
                     tri[index + 1] = i + 1;
                     tri[index + 2] = i + 2;
                 }
             }

             mesh.triangles = tri;
             Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
             Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];
             for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
             {
                 normals[i] = Vector3.forward;
                 colors[i] = color;
             }
             mesh.normals = normals;
             mesh.colors = colors;

             meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
         }
```

I know I "could just use the LineRenderer shipped with Unity, it is faster then anything you'll ever write", but that's not the point here. 
I am trying to **understand meshes** and see where I can tweak my code to **improve it's performance**.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Well i am not sure if i understood what you look as an answer but i am working on point clouds and meshes in Unity as well. What i have done is at first i used `Coroutines` to improve performance but when to yield was a big problem for big data like i have. Now i am creating a new thread and create my meshes there which i dont know if slowew or not because Unity hang all the time in other approach  but at least Unity does not hang anymore with this one. But you have to be careful with multi thread programming in Unity. You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ja63QO1Imck).

Comment: @AliKanat thanks for the comment. I am actually open to anything, basically looking for some input, ideas and tips for improvement... I'll definitely check out your link, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You can almost double the speed by removing extra memory allocation.  Since Vector3 is a value type, they are already allocated when you allocate the array.  Vector3.forward also allocates a new Vector3 each time, and we can re-use it.

```
public static void createCircle(MeshFilter meshFilter, float innerRadius, float outerRadius, Color color, float xPosition = 0, float yPosition = 0, float startDegree = 0, float endDegree = 360, int points = 100)
 {
     Mesh mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
     mesh.Clear();

     //These values will result in no (or very ugly in the case of points < 10) circle, so let's safe calculation and just return an empty mesh!
     if (startDegree == endDegree || points < 10 || innerRadius >= outerRadius || innerRadius < 0 || outerRadius <= 0)
     {
         return;
     }

     //The points for the full circle shall be whatever is given but if its not the full circle we dont need all the points!
     points = (int)(Mathf.Abs(endDegree - startDegree) / 360f * points);

     //We always need an uneven number of points!
     if (points % 2 != 0) { points++; }

     Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[points];
     float degreeStepSize = (endDegree - startDegree) * 2 / (points - 3);
     float halfRadStepSize = (degreeStepSize) * Mathf.Deg2Rad / 2f;
     float startRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * startDegree;
     float endRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * endDegree;

     //Let's save the vector at the beginning and the one on the end to make a perfectly straight line
     vertices[0] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(startRad) * outerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(startRad) * outerRadius + yPosition, 0);
     vertices[vertices.Length - 1] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(endRad) * innerRadius + xPosition, Mathf.Cos(endRad) * innerRadius + yPosition, 0);

     for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Length - 1; i++)
     {
         //Pure coinsidence that saved some calculatons. Half Step Size is the same as what would needed to be calculated here!
         float rad = (i - 1) * halfRadStepSize + startRad;
         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             vertices[i].x = Mathf.Sin(rad) * outerRadius + xPosition;
             vertices[i].y = Mathf.Cos(rad) * outerRadius + yPosition;
             vertices[i].z = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             vertices[i].x = Mathf.Sin(rad) * innerRadius + xPosition;
             vertices[i].y = Mathf.Cos(rad) * innerRadius + yPosition;
             vertices[i].z = 0;;
         }
     }
     mesh.vertices = vertices;

     int[] tri = new int[(vertices.Length - 2) * 3];
     for (int i = 0; i < (vertices.Length - 2); i++)
     {
         int index = i * 3;
         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             tri[index + 0] = i + 0;
             tri[index + 1] = i + 2;
             tri[index + 2] = i + 1;
         }
         else
         {
             tri[index + 0] = i + 0;
             tri[index + 1] = i + 1;
             tri[index + 2] = i + 2;
         }
     }

     mesh.triangles = tri;
     Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
     Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];

    var f = Vector3.forward;

     for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
     {
         normals[i].x= f.x;
         normals[i].y= f.y;
         normals[i].z= f.z;
         colors[i] = color;
     }
     mesh.normals = normals;
     mesh.colors = colors;

     meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
 }
```